# How to access PostgreSQL arrays within PL/TCL

Tags: postgresql, tcl

How does one access an array passed into pl/tcl function?  Shouldn't the parameter get turned into a list? In the code below it prints "1" no matter what the input is, like "select foobar(array[1,2,3]);"

I am interested in this is to build custom aggregates which use arrays to hold state between calls.

EDIT:

Here is a new function:

```
create function foobar(int[]) returns int[] as $$
    elog INFO "$1, [llength $1]"
    return $1
$$ language pltcl;
```

Here is the call and output, which shows that getting arrays in and out of the function works:

```
postgis20=# select (array[1,2,3])[1];
 array
-------
     1
(1 row)

postgis20=# select foobar(array[1,2,3]);
INFO:  {1,2,3}, 1
 foobar
---------
 {1,2,3}
(1 row)

postgis20=# select (foobar(array[1,2,3]))[1];
INFO:  {1,2,3}, 1
 foobar
--------
      1
(1 row)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Good question! Is it possible to print the _whole_ array from within the Tcl code? (That will either just work in an “unexpected” way, or will fail in a hopefully-informative way.) I don't have a PostgreSQL installation, so I can't just test, so I'm really restricted in what I can do other than asking questions…

Comment: @Donal.  See the new edits.  Thanks for looking. FYI: Postgres is an easy install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/pltcl.html) is a little gnostic, but it includes this:

> The argument values supplied to a PL/Tcl function's code are simply the input arguments converted to text form (just as if they had been displayed by a `SELECT` statement). Conversely, the `return` command will accept any string that is acceptable input format for the function's declared return type. So, within the PL/Tcl function, all values are just text strings.

So the array value from Tcl's PoV is going to be `{1,2,3}` or something like that. Everything else is converting between that serialization and Tcl's lists. (All this will also work just fine for other types of numeric array, but will be dangerous if you do arrays of characters or strings, as the delimiter characters can appear within. Of course, in that case I'd also think you were doing something a bit wrong in the first place…)

### Handling PostgreSQL `int[]` arrays

To extract the integers from such a thing, we'd do:

```
set tclListOfValues [split [string trim $1 "{}"] ","]
```

After that, you can use `llength` and `lindex` and `foreach` and so on. The reverse operation, converting a Tcl list (assumed to be of integers) to an `int[]` for returning:

```
return \{[join $tclListOfValues ","]\}
```

### Handling nested PostgreSQL arrays

Things will get a lot more awkward if you need to access nested arrays. The issue is that it's a two-level split, and that's best done by applying some clever magic with `string map` before the outer `split`:

```
set listOfLists {}
foreach innerArray [split [string map {"\},\{" "\u0000"} [string trim $1 "{}"]] "\u0000"] {
    lappend listOfLists [split $innerArray ","]
}
```

In Tcl 8.6, you can do this slightly more neatly with `lmap` like this (conceptually a one-liner, but broken up for clarity):

```
set listOfLists [lmap innerArray \
        [split [string map {"\},\{" "\u0000"} [string trim $1 "{}"]] "\u0000"] {
    split $innerArray ","
}]
```

In the reverse direction:

```
set resultAccumulator {}
foreach innerList $listOfLists {
    lappend resultAccumulator [join $innerList ","]
}
return \{[join $resultAccumulator "\},\{"]\}
```

Or in Tcl 8.6 style with `lmap` again:

```
return \{[join [lmap innerList $listOfLists {join $innerList ","}] "\},\{"]\}
```

Comment: Thanks!.  At some point I will have to compare speeds for this PL/PGSQL -- It feels like it would be much slower due to string splitting, but maybe that is all that PL/PGSQL does anyway.